In BigQuery Studio, is there a way to bring all the column names of a table as text into the query editor?
In MySQL Workbench, you can expand a table schema in the Navigator panel, expand the columns menu, and drag all of the column names to the query editor window to populate the query with the names of the columns.
Dragging Columns to Editor in MySQL Workbench
It is generally accepted as best practice to specifically define the columns you want to query, rather than simply running a SELECT * statement. I have not yet discovered an easy way to perform a similar action in BigQuery Studio. Does anyone know of an easy way to bring the columns of a table into the BQ query editor window, without typing out each column by hand?
In BQ, I've already tried to copy the schema to table and JSON, which contains the column names, but I then have to delete a bunch of extra DDL text that is not relevant to a select statement.
Copying as Table or JSON in BigQuery
Any suggestions?

After posting my question, I kept digging in the BigQuery UI to find a solution, and I found a partial solution!
In the BigQuery Studio editor, when you select a table and view the schema tab, you see the field names listed out. If you click the field names themselves, BQ Studio will create an untitled query window in split view mode, and add the column names you click to the query window, along with the required SELECT statement dialogue. While not quite the same experience as MySQL Workbench, this is a solid workaround for my purposes.
GIF showing clicking to add column names in BigQuery Studio

Oh wow!!!  That is a FANTASTIC find!!!  I'll be using that from now on.  TY SOOO much for creating the response AND the excellent GIF.

New in BigQuery is a concept called Data Canvas.  This allows you to examine a table and, in the context of that table, specify new queries related to the table.  One of the capabilities is to enter a GenAI prompt that is then satisfied by Google's Gemini LLM.  One can then express what one desires to achieve and BigQuery Data Canvas will then generate the SQL.  I just tested a prompt of "select each of the columns" and it generated a perfect SQL query that listed (explicitly) each of the columns.  See attached screen shot.  This seems to address your question and maybe more ... the Data Canvas query can be used to a much broader effect.
Here is a link to the documentation Data Canvas.
And here is a link to a YouTube video illustrating it.

Thank you for pointing out this feature. While it would solve my problem, and many others, if I had access to it, sadly, my organization does not allow access to it yet. But it looks like a very useful, powerful tool! If my org opens it up to us, I'd gladly give it a shot.
